# How to print duration of media and style slider | JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, slider

I am making a music player for my college project and facing some issues with Sliders.

### Here are the things I want to do with Seeking Bar:

1. How to style the seeking slider? (-fx-accent is not working).
2. How to print total time of song, and the current time at which song is playing.

Below is the code I'm using for seekSlider:

```
package musicplayer;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.MapChangeListener;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.util.Duration;



public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button playbtn;
    @FXML
    private Button pausebtn;
    @FXML
    private Button stopbtn;
    @FXML
    private Button open;
    @FXML
    private Slider seekSlider;
    @FXML
    private Slider volumeSlider;
    @FXML
    private Label durationLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label musicBox;
    @FXML
    private Label playTime;
    @FXML
    private ImageView albumCover;
    @FXML
    private ImageView playbtnimg;

    @FXML
    private MediaView mv; 
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private Media me;
    Double duration;
    File selectedFile = null;
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     * @param e
     */

    //Open button code for choosing file through FileChooser
     public void open(ActionEvent e){


        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
        //Extension filter for showing mp3 and m4a files
        fc.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("MP3", "*.mp3"),new
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("M4A", "*.m4a"));
        selectedFile = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

        //If runs when user selects a file
        if(selectedFile != null){

        String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath(); //gets the path of file
        if(mp!=null) //This if works when any song is playing
        {
            mp.stop(); //Stops the currently playing music

            //Change the album art to default.png
            File file = new File("src/musicplayer/default.png");
            Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
            albumCover.setImage(image);
        }

        path = path.replace("\\","/");
        me = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
        mp = new MediaPlayer(me);
        mv.setMediaPlayer(mp);
        //Code for Volume Slider 
        volumeSlider.setValue(0.7 * 100);
        volumeSlider.valueProperty().addListener((Observable observable) -> {
        mp.setVolume(volumeSlider.getValue()/100);
        });
        //Code for seeking bar

        seekSlider.maxProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
            () -> mp.getTotalDuration().toSeconds(),
            mp.totalDurationProperty()));

        mp.currentTimeProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observable, Duration oldValue, Duration newValue) -> {
            seekSlider.setValue(newValue.toSeconds());
        });

        seekSlider.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {
            mp.seek(Duration.seconds(seekSlider.getValue()));
        });






        mp.play(); //Plays the selected song

        me.getMetadata().addListener(new MapChangeListener<String, Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change<? extends String, ? extends Object> ch) {
          if (ch.wasAdded()) {
            handleMetadata(ch.getKey(), ch.getValueAdded());
          }
        }

            private void handleMetadata(String key, Object value) {        
                if(key.equals("title")){   
                    musicBox.setText(value.toString());
                    }
                if(key.equals("image")){
                    albumCover.setImage((Image)value);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    public void play(ActionEvent e){
    mp.play();
    }

    public void pause(ActionEvent e){
    mp.pause();
    }

    public void stop(ActionEvent e){
    mp.stop();
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {


    }



}
```

I am using playTime Label to display totalDuration and durationLabel to display current time.
Also, check the code of seekSlider, Sometimes, it does not works properly while dragging.

Comment: Start by replacing seekSlider.setOnMouseClicked with `seekSlider.valueProperty().addListener`.  A slider is controlled by more than mouse clicks.

Comment: @VGR can you give me full code for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a Label and bind its text property to a binding that formats the MediaPlayer’s current time:

```
Label timeLabel = new Label();
timeLabel.textProperty().bind(
    Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
            Duration time = mp.getCurrentTime();
            return String.format("%4d:%02d:%04.1f",
                (int) time.toHours(),
                (int) time.toMinutes() % 60,
                time.toSeconds() % 3600);
        },
        mp.currentTimeProperty()));
```

Note that you should not listen to mouse input, since controls can be manipulated with the keyboard and screen touches.  It’s better to listen to the value property instead:

```
Slider seekSlider = new Slider(0, 1, 0);
seekSlider.maxProperty().bind(
    Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
        () -> mp.getTotalDuration().toSeconds(),
        mp.totalDurationProperty()));

mp.currentTimeProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    seekSlider.setValue(newValue.toSeconds());
});

seekSlider.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    mp.seek(Duration.seconds(newValue.doubleValue()));
});
```

Note that some properties of a MediaPlayer are likely to be meaningless when it’s first constructed, since it loads the media in the background.  For instance, the initial value of [totalDuration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#totalDurationProperty) is likely to be Duration.UNKNOWN.

You can deal with this by moving all code that depends on the MediaPlayer into a Runnable, and passing that Runnable to [setOnReady](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnReady-java.lang.Runnable-):

```
Label timeLabel = new Label();
Slider seekSlider = new Slider();

mp.setOnReady(() -> {
    timeLabel.textProperty().bind(
        Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
                Duration time = mp.getCurrentTime();
                return String.format("%4d:%02d:%04.1f",
                    (int) time.toHours(),
                    (int) time.toMinutes() % 60,
                    time.toSeconds() % 3600);
            },
            mp.currentTimeProperty()));

    seekSlider.maxProperty().bind(
        Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
            () -> mp.getTotalDuration().toSeconds(),
            mp.totalDurationProperty()));

    mp.currentTimeProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        seekSlider.setValue(newValue.toSeconds());
    });

    seekSlider.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        mp.seek(Duration.seconds(newValue.doubleValue()));
    });
});
```

Comment: When I used your code for listener, the song does not plays properly anymore.
And is it necessary to use: Slider seekSlider = new Slider(0, 1, 0);

Comment: Actually you can use any Slider constructor, as long as the minimum value is allowed to have its default value, zero.  Can you provide more detail than just “does not play properly anymore”?  What are you seeing?  Are you playing a video, or just audio?

Comment: I am just playing audios
Can you provide mail id, fb id or something else, so that I can send you code and we can contact more properly ?

Comment: By "does not play properly anymore" I mean that whenever I load a song, previously it starts to play as soon as it is opened
But after using your code, it does not play, whenever I keep dragging the slider, It plays the part of song at which the mouse is placed on slider
As soon as I remove the mouse, it stops

Comment: You are using [setOnReady](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnReady-java.lang.Runnable-) to initialize your Slider and Label only once the media’s properties are known, right?

Comment: Actually No
I've updated the full code of my Controller file, you can see there

Comment: Updated answer with setOnReady example.